# R cannot be resolved to a variable - a new case?

Tags: android, cordova, build-error

OK, so I've read something like 10 other threads here regarding this infamous issue, and tried every possible solution offered - without any luck.

I have a Phonegap project that I worked on a few months ago, and have to create a new version now. So, on my new Mac - the old Mac is no longer available to me, I checked out the code which I used to make the previous build (so there can't be anything wrong with the actual code, since it hasn't changed). Since my new Mac didn't have Eclipse installed I downloaded the Android SDK and discovered it came with a preconfigured version of Eclipse, so I used that.

Just to be on the safe side I have installed all the SDK versions. Sadly I have to target Android 2.3.3, with a  minimum version of 2.1. I have made sure this is configured correctly in the project.

All my .xml and .png files under the "res" folder have valid lowercase names. There are no errors in the XML files, at least Eclipse doesn't complain about anything in them - and like I stated above, the XML files haven't changed since the last time I successfully built the app.

I have made sure the permissions of the Android Developer Tools are correct (everyone has read access).

I have deleted the "gen" folder and tried building again. I've done "clean" countless times. I've restarted Eclipse countless times.

I have made sure the package names are synchronized everywhere. I have made sure I don't have "import android.R" anywhere.

The "gen" folder is created every time Eclipse tries to build, but it doesn't include the R.java file, it only includes the file BuildConfig.java which in addition to the package declaration contains this:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

My res/values/strings.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
    <string name="app_name">My App Name</string>

</resources>
```

My res/xml/plugins.xml file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="com.phonegap.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="com.phonegap.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="com.phonegap.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="com.phonegap.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="com.phonegap.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="com.phonegap.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="com.phonegap.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="com.phonegap.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="Crypto" value="com.phonegap.CryptoHandler"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="com.phonegap.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="Network Status" value="com.phonegap.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="com.phonegap.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="com.phonegap.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="com.phonegap.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="com.phonegap.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="com.phonegap.Capture"/>

    <plugin name="EncapPlugin" value="no.encap.securitytoken.phonegap.plugin.EncapPlugin" />
</plugins>
```

My res/layout/main.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried changing `fill_parent` with `match_parent` above, since I read in one of the answers that it had been renamed to that in version 8 of the API - but that didn't help. Anyway, I need to support version 7 of the API as well. Just in case, I tried changing the names as stated and setting the minimum version to 8, but that didn't help.

Eclipse generates no other errors, and only one benign and unrelated warning, when trying to build.

My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="no.encap.securitytoken.phonegap"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /><supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
                android:name="EncapMain"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><activity
            android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Since this is a PhoneGap app the XML files really only contain the bare minimum required to get a WebView up and running.

Anyone have any idea what could be wrong here? This R.java thing really seems like a very weak point for the Android Developer Tools - and improved handling of build errors related to this (explaining *what* is wrong) seems like a thing that could benefit from being prioritized. Anyway - I hope someone can help!

**UPDATE:** The problem is caused by Subversion. I'm not sure exactly what it is Subversion is doing that's causing this, but whenever I make a new project and import my files to get Eclipse to compile the project everything works fine. Then, whenever I do something in Subversion, like add/delete/commit/update an HTML, CSS or Javascript file (in the assets folder) this error returns and I have to make a new project again.

Comment: I don't thing that "R.java" is a weak point: it is not the cause, but the symptom of something going wrong. If something, somewhere goes wrong and it cannot be generated, you get this error, but you should also get another error (in the problems tab for instance). If you don't it's the fault of that part not reporting itself, and not necessarily of the whole "R.java" thing

Comment: what the Console is saying ??

Comment: Not all errors are printed in `Problems` tab, please check also `Console` tab for errors.

Comment: The error reporting in regards to this R.java thing isn't good - it should be able to tell you which file caused the R.java to not be generated, at the least. My Console tab is empty, and the only error in the Problems tab is this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made little mistake in building of gen ..so check is there any sort of mistake in your xml file or generated file..

After clean and build also if its not working then do the simple work..

create new project copy the code and layout and the .png xml plugins etc don't even delete the gen folder then

After clean and build run project it will work

check this [link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/fixed-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html) for more help

Comment: Accepted this answer because the only way to fix my problem was make a new project from scratch and copy the code and resource files from the old project.

Answer (score 1):

**Reasons** for missing R.java could be

- When you dont properly name your drawables
- When there is some issue with your layouts
- When you forget to register things (Activity etc) in AndroidManifest
  file
- When there is a conflict in package name in manifest and some other
  place
- Sometimes multiple pacakges can arise this issue

**Tip: Look at the error in the Console and see where does it refer, that is the only lead !!**

**Fact:** Cleaning the project does not solve the problem always

Comment: None of these are the case here, as already mentioned in the question. These very same files were successfully built on another Mac with an older version of Eclipse a few months ago.

Comment: Refer to your manifest file. Make sure the package name inside the **manifest** tag is the same you are using through out. P.s in your activities tag I smell somehting uneven, check that out too.

Comment: As is you have an activity "MainActivity" a normal practice to name it is **android:name=".MainActivity"** but your naming mehtod is diferent for both of your activities

Comment: I think this project was created with an old version of the developer tools and it's using a very old version of PhoneGap (since renamed Cordova) - so it's likely something has changed in the Android Developer Tools so that they now require more or different settings somewhere. I may just have to bite the bullet on this one and make a new project from scratch and move my code and resource files over.

Comment: that would hardly take 15-30 minutes :-) P.s the reason you are metoning is not valid enough becaus all the new versions support the previous one ! **<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="15"
           />** This line takes care of it if this was the case..
You need to admitt that the problem is somewhere within your project

Comment: I'm not sure how the error could be within my project if there haven't bee changes to the requirements for these files in the developer tools - because I had no problem building these exact same files (same Eclipse project even) a few months ago, with an older version of the developer tools. Anyway... I've made a new project from scratch now (took at least 30 minutes, since this is the first time I've created such a project) and it's working now.

Comment: Congrats :-) There would be a regret somewhere in you mind that what happened to the older one and you would be living with the fear not to  get it again  :-P

Answer (score 1):

I had made an update of all sdk's and then I got the famous "R cannot...".
Turns out all build-tools had been deleted during the update of the sdk's.
Check "SDk Manager" that you have all tools installed.